# Facebook API /me/posts return only 275 post as limit

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I make a GET request to /me/posts to get posts on the profile and set the limit to 1000 I only get 275 post as max.
I'm sure that there is more than 1000 post not only 275.
is 275 the max limit.

PS: I'm using Angular to make requests and Package called ng-facebook to handle the API requests

Comment: Check to the api plugin how it works, may be there limitTo functionality, or try using facebook's graph api directly

Comment: I set the limit to 276 but still getting 275.
I tried the graph api directly from here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
and still get the same result

Comment: you should use a lower limit (like 100) and use paging instead

Comment: @luschn how could I use paging

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: Thanks :D it helped a lot can you post it in an answer so I mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use paging in your application and show few results like `10,50,100` on a single page. Use following link for the same.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging